# Open Ended Pledges

Tags: pledges

The New Pledge form asks for a total amount of the pledge. I'm working from a spreadsheet where the installment is specified but not a total amount. What is the best way to enter this?

Comment: It was suggested that I treat these as recurring contributions, however these payments are made by EFT and not by credit card so I cannot see how to do that for EFT.

We are in Thailand so the iATS process probably will not work.

Comment: We are initially going to do everything manually until we can find a Thai payment processor. Anybody know one?

Answer (score 2):

The "recurring payments" approach will only work if you have a CiviCRM payment processor extension that supports it.  Other than iATS and [CiviSEPA](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civisepa-sepa-direct-debit-extension) I'm not sure other extensions support ACH/EFT - though I'm not familiar with the non-US processor extensions.

It could be that [CiviBanking](https://github.com/Project60/org.project60.banking) could provide a solution for you.
Another possibility is the [Offline Recurring Payment](https://civicrm.org/extensions/offline-recurring-payment) extension.

You can also check out the [Direct Credit and Direct Debit wiki page](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/Direct+Debit+and+Direct+Credit+-+Monthly+Batches).